# Node.js streams for XML transformations with xml-stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm using [xml-stream](https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream) to read a large XML file.  I'd like to:

1. pipe collected elements to a stream
2. optionally, to transform those elements using one or more pipes
3. pipe the result to an http response

Here is `xml-stream` snippet collecting required elements:

```
xml.on('endElement: item', function(item) {
  // pipe item to stream
})
```

How do I build streams for step 1 and 2?

P.S. `xml-stream` has only `console.log` examples

UPDATE 1

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
stream = require('stream');

let liner = new stream.Transform( { objectMode: true } );

liner._transform = function (data, encoding, done) {
  this.push(data);
  console.log(data);
  console.log('======================='); 
  done();
};

let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileNames[0]);

let xmlStream = new XmlStream(fileStream);

let counter = 0;

xmlStream.on('endElement: Item', function(el) {
  liner.write(el);
  counter += 1;
});

xmlStream.on('end', function() {
  console.log(counter);
  liner.end();
});
```

`_transform` get called on every `write`, however piping `liner` stream to http result doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mission accomplished.  The function below returns `transform stream` that can be piped to any writable stream.  `liner._flush` is necessary only you want to add some data in the end of the stream.

P.S. A handy module (not used here) https://github.com/rvagg/through2

```
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const XmlStream = require('xml-stream');

function getTransformStream() { 

  let liner = new stream.Transform( { objectMode: true } );

  liner._transform = function (data, encoding, done) {
    // have your transforms here
    this.push(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log('=======================');
    done();
  };

  liner._flush = function (done) {
    console.log('DONE DONE DONE DONE');
    done();
  };


  let fileStream = fs.createReadStream('filename');

  let xmlStream = new XmlStream(fileStream);

  let counter = 0;

  xmlStream.on('endElement: Item', function(el) {
    liner.write(JSON.stringify(el));
    counter += 1;
  });

  xmlStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(counter);
    liner.end();
  });

  return liner;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it's getting there, but how do you deal with back pressure?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the example, that the library provides. If you have done that, it would be nice if you have pointed that out.
So I use  Promised land for data flow and Highlandjs to create a stream from array, which has only one element- the `item`.

At the end, you have stream, which you can use according to Highland docs.

```
    var Land = require('promised-land')
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'file.xml'));
    var xml = new XmlStream(stream);
    xml.preserve('item', true);
    xml.collect('subitem');
    var arr = []
    xml.on('endElement: item', function(item) {
    arr.push(item)
    });
    xml.on('end', function(data) {
        var highlandStream = _(data)
        Land.emit('endStream', highlandStream)
    });
    Land.promise('endStream').then(function(stream) {
    // now you can pipe your stream
    })
```

Still, it is possible much more simpler and smarter solution if you use some of the alternative Node.js libraries for reading XML files.

I recommend node-modules.com and libraries.io/npm to improve the NPM search.

Comment: I did check it, but it doesn't have a case of writing to another stream, it only uses `console.log`.  I figured out 1/2 already.

Comment: Why don't parse XML to json. Then you will have more options.

Comment: This is what `xml-stream` does, but using streams, not loading everything to memory like `xml2js`, which won't work well if you have 1GB XML files.

Comment: I see. Take a look at http://highlandjs.org/#_(source) and maybe you can find simpler way to create stream out of XML file.

Comment: Check my update.  I got it half working already.  However it's still not piping to http result.

Comment: Can you pipe it to a writeable stream?

Comment: Yes, but so far it doesn't work.  `_transform` gets called on every `write`, however piping `liner` stream to http result doesn't produce any output.

Comment: If I can pipe it successfully to another xml file on the system, then I will proceed in testing out piping simple stream to http. At the end I will merge the the solutions.

Comment: I'm getting close.  Now I have it piped to html response, however it's all `[object Object][object Object][object Object]` etc :)